# Using 'find' to select unknown patterns in file names with bash

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a directory with 4 files in it.

```
path/to/files/1_A
path/to/files/1_B
path/to/files/2_A
path/to/files/2_B
```

I want to create a loop, which on each iteration, does something with two files, a matching X_A and X_B. I need to know how to `find` these files, which sounds simple enough using pattern matching. The problem is, there are too many files, and I do not know the prefixes aka patterns (1_ and 2_ in the example). Is there some way to group files in a directory based on the first few characters in the filename? (Ultimately to store as a variable to be used in a loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the 3-character prefixes by printing out all the file names, trimming them to three characters, and then getting the unique strings.

```
find -printf '%f\n' | cut -c -3 | sort -u
```

Then if you wanted to loop over each prefix, you could write a loop like:

```
find -printf '%f\n' | cut -c -3 | sort -u | while IFS= read -r prefix; do
    echo "Looking for $prefix*..."
    find -name "$prefix*"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm on OSX and ran into some difficulty with `find` and illegal operations so I ran a `brew install findutils` followed by a `alias find=gfind` and everything worked great.